# Change header text on pages in DinkToPdf

Tags: dinktopdf

Hi I am using DinkToPdf to generate pdfs in dotnet.  Just wondering if anyone knows of a way to change the header on some of the pages? eg. Page 1 has a certain header, Page 2-10 a different header and pages 10-20 have a different header again.

I was wondering if I have to generate 3 pdfs and then stitch them back together at the end?